# How to populate javascript model from html table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having follwoing type of  dynamic UI through table on my page

```
<table id="tblUserAttendance">
 <tr id="135"> <td> 1 </td>
               <td> Student 1 </td> 
               <td> <input checked="checked" name="rdo135" type="radio" value="true" /> Pre 
                    <input name="rdo135" type="radio" value="false" /> Absent
               </td>
 </tr>
<tr id="136"> <td> 1 </td>
               <td> Student 1 </td> 
               <td> <input checked="checked" name="rdo136" type="radio" value="true" /> Pre 
                    <input name="rdo136" type="radio" value="false" /> Absent
               </td>
 </tr>
<tr id="137"> <td> 1 </td>
               <td> Student 1 </td> 
               <td> <input checked="checked" name="rdo137" type="radio" value="true" /> Pre 
                    <input name="rdo137" type="radio" value="false" /> Absent
               </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to populate following type of model using above table dynamically to post data to server.

```
var student = {};
  student.Id = Id;//where Id may be equal to 135
  studnet.IsPresent = true;// if that particualar radio button is checked  else false
```

i want to create array of such students which should be equal to the number of rows in the above table.

Can you please tell how to achieve this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: you are going the wrong way. the view renders data from the controller not the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery will create you an array of student objects:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    var result = [];
    var students = $.each($('#tblUserAttendance tr'), function (i, e) {
        var studentData = $('td', e);
        var checks = $('input', studentData[2]);
        var student = { id: e.id, name: studentData[1].textContent, active: checks[0].checked };
        result[i] = student;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: great @m1kael , so using above query now we can have id and name of each student , but how to get the value of radio button group , can u suggest a jquery selector within the same answer to achieve that

Comment: I think this line  var student = { id: e.id, name: studentData[1].textContent };
should be  var student = { id: e.id, IsPresent: studentData[1].is(':checked') };
 Am I right ?

Comment: Updated my answer. .is(':checked') would do it too but only when called on an input, not a td (studentData[1] is a td).

Comment: My approach is the same, so I won't bother adding a separate answer. http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/s3rzy/

Comment: Thanks Richard + 1 for ur approach